# How can I convert my plain text (r,s) signature to a format that openssl can verify?

Tags: encryption, public-key, cryptography

I have my (r,s) in the following format: `["r","442ca7cb054a9862ed93848cc13e0134968eba79db89e0e6f9ded510149aacd1","s","5494856cc4e6ea054480605bcdf9a643f7efe0020e369fa01e5bab5d108bdbd7"]`
How can I convert the signature to a format that openssl can process (DER, ASN.1) and be able to verify it?
I was trying to run `openssl dgst -sha1 -verify publKey.pem -signature signature SamplePDF.pdf`, signature being a .file file which contains the text previously mentioned.
Also worth mentioning I am using ECDSA and secp256k1 curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both your r and s values are "low-half" i.e. their first byte (hex 44 or 54) is less than hex 80, if you have (or get) `xxd`:

```
 echo 30440220{rval_in_hex}0220{sval_in_hex} | xxd -p -r >sigfile
```

Or if you have bash or GNU or maybe other printf (correction: POSIX is not sufficient):

```
 printf "$( echo ...asabove... | sed 's/../\\x&/g' )" >sigfile
```

Or more complicated but works for "high-half" values as well, create a file containing

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:seq
[seq]
r=INTEGER:0x{rvalue_in_hex}
s=INTEGER:0x{svalue_in_hex}
```

then run `openssl asn1parse -genconf thatfile -out sigfile`. On some shells instead of a permanent file you can create a temporary file like this:

```
openssl asn1parse -genconf <( printf "%s\n" "asn1=SEQUENCE:seq" "[seq]" ... ) -out sigfile
```

Note best practice is to match the strength of the hash with the PKC, so with secp256k1 you should use SHA256 (or SHA3-256 if available e.g. OpenSSL 1.1.1 and you prefer) otherwise you're basically throwing away some of the security you spent resources on. Especially since SHA1 has been broken for collision; see https://shattered.io and numerous related Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, the "more complicated" method worked like a charm!